# Using the stem filename taken from command line input with extension separately inside python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I have taken a command line input as

> dataset = sys.argv[1]

Where suppose I have a stem data set named as : IRIS

Now there are 3 extensions of this IRIS dataset, i.e IRIS.names, IRIS.data, IRIS.test

Suppose in my code at a particular point I need to use the dataset `IRIS.names`

How can I do it?

I have tried like :

```
with open(dataset".names") as f:


with open("dataset.names") as f:
```

These above two are giving me errors.

If I write `with open("IRIS.names") as f:` then this will work fine. But I am not supposed to write the file name directly inside my program, instead I need to take the stem file name (i.e IRIS) as command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is just string concatenation.

```
with open(dataset+".names") as f:
```